# How to change the body width when the browser window is resized, so that the content is easily read?

Tags: javascript, css, browser, resize

Here, the web page is displayed in a 1349x659 browser window. (it's exactly the dimensions of the image). With the body width set to 60%, the content is nicely packed and easily read.

[image: 1349x659]

Here I have resized the browser window to 478x642. And you can see that the 60% body width no longer gives the good view.

[image: 478x642]

Since the web page can be resized without the server even knowing, the solution must be in the client side. Or done in the css file.

I suggest this algorithm:

If the visitor is mobile, then the body width should be 100% regardless of any other thing.

If the visitor is not mobile (tablet, pc, ...) then (

If the width of the browser window is larger than the height, body width will be equal to the window height.

but if the width is less than the height, then the body width is 100%.
)

Here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/rawj7vxc/

```
<body>
Some posts are not public. To access them, please login to your account, or register if you have none yet. By logging in to your account, you're no longer considered a "guest", this has some benefits which come with account promotions. Seeing more posts is one of those benefits. Registered accounts need verification. You'll be told how to this after the first unverified login. The verification will, however, not be immediate.
</body>

body {
background-color: rgb(31,25,0);
width: 60%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;

font-family: consalos;
text-align: justify;
color: rgb(215,200,0);

overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I think there's no need of JS for this. Only to set proper css rules on the appropriate media queries:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/?hl=en#responsive-web-design

Comment: You can use media queries https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: try `media queries`

Comment: @SagarV never heard of them. reading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into using media queries. These will allow you to cater your design to the width and height of your screen.

```
/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

    }

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: This is great, but is it possible to compare the height and width of the screen and then act based on the result?

Comment: You can combine min max height and width in a media query to get what you are after.
`@media (min-height: 500px) and (min-width: 580px) {
    /* CSS stuff */
}`

Comment: But there is no way to say thing like `current-height < current-width` am I right?

Comment: I'd look into jQuery for conditional logic like that. Not entirely sure if you can do that with pure CSS, but jQuery would work great.

Comment: Nice. Can you please provide a link?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some framework like Bootstrap or media queries:

```
@media (min-width: 568px) {
  .myDiv{
    width: 550px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .myDiv{
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .myDiv{
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

Here you have more information: [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
And also about Bootstrap: [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the metatag ***viewport*** ([see documentation here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp))

> viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to
>   control the page's dimensions and scaling.
>
> The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the
>   screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).
>
> The initial-scale=1.0 part sets the initial zoom level when the page
>   is first loaded by the browser.

In your `head` section, simply add following tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If you want to add `width: 60%` only when the screen is "wide" you could use:

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  body {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

See [here](https://jsbin.com/gomayetaco/1)

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: hmm, so that scale=1 is the translation of what I want... but I put that tag in the `<head>` and it didn't work.

Comment: Could you share a fiddle?

Comment: added the fiddle.

Comment: It's still 60% in narrow windows. https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7EXB.jpg  I  am using waterfox.

Comment: If you want set width to 60% only when the screen is "wide", see my update please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138718/discussion-between-ahb-and-alessandro-maglioccola).

Answer (score -1):

Ok, here is my solution with pure javascript,

```
document.getElementByTagName("body").onresize=function(){

  var fullwidth=screen.width;
  var fullheight=screen.height;

  if(fullwidth<aval){                     //checking if mobile
     /*
      * make width 100%
      */
  }
  else
  {
        if(fullwidth>fullheight)
             //make width = fullheight
        else
             // make width=100%
  }
}
```

I have given you the logic structure only, if you want full css change(width and height change) code, mention here.

**N.B. aval is the threshold value under which screen size device will be treated as mobile device**

Comment: and what is `aval`??

Comment: Does this code run each time the resize event occurs?

Comment: aval is a particular threshold value below which screen width will be treated as mobile device

Comment: @AHB just mention this <body onresize="myFunction()"> and keep the code inside myFunction

Comment: edit the code with proper value of `aval` and the downvote may either reversed or cancelled.

Comment: @SagarV keeping it aval I am giving more flexibility, it depends on the programmer which will be the threshold value for mobile screen.

Comment: what about this one : `if(fullwidth>fullheight)//make width = fullheigt` you make body a square which op didn't want.

Comment: He mentioned as "If the width of the browser window is larger than the height, body width will be equal to the window height."

Comment: whatever, seems pretty irrelevant. Anyway, I removed my vote.